# to show alert in browser by express.js

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I'm using express to send email by `nodemailer` module.
 my code is following:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
const output = `
<p>You have new one contact request</p>
<h3>Contact Details</h3>
<ul>
<li>Name:${req.body.name}</li>
<li>Email:${req.body.email}</li>
</ul>
<h3>Message</h3>
<p>${req.body.message}</p>
`;

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: 'mymail@gamil.com', // generated ethereal user
        pass: '2020' // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

// send mail with defined transport object
let mailOptions = {
    from: "mymail@gamil.com", // sender address
    to: "myfriend@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "the subject", // Subject line
    html: output // html body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    // , info.res
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodeMailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
   res.render('index', { msg: 'email has been sent' });
    res.redirect('back');
});});
```

after clicking `submit` button, below code redirects to the Contact page:

```
        res.redirect('back');
```

and then shows a message by this code:

```
       res.render('index', { msg: 'email has been sent' });
```

now my aim is to instead of showing text by the forementioned code, showing the text in an alert box.
what I've tried for is like:

```
res.render('index','<script>alert("email has been sent")</script>');
```

but this doesn't work.so any idea and solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you send email from backend

So, to alert in browser, you should send some signal to frontend. By socket, by request from frontend or any other way

**Edit:**

This code show alert with message from backend

front (part of **index.ejs**):

```
  <script lang="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var isAlert = <%= isAlert %>;

      if (isAlert === true) {
        var alertTitle = "<%= alertTitle %>";

        console.log(alertTitle);
        alert(alertTitle);
      }
    })
  </script>
```

backend:

```
  res.render('index', { isAlert: true, alertTitle: "Oops!" })
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: @A Ralkov yes right and as you can see it's sent now by `msg`.but I want to put alert instead.

Comment: want to when the send of the form is validated by `nodemailer`, pop up the alert in browser

Comment: @A Ralkov this line `var isAlert = <%= isAlert %>;` is not matched.it has a syntax error